# Как переназначить клавиши Linux

Tags: linux, hotkeys

Нужно переназначить в Linux консоли (не графического интерфейса) клавиши <kbd>Ctrl_Right</kbd> на <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> или продублировать <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
(ubuntu server)

Comment: можно добавить пару строк в файл /etc/inputrc или ~/.inputrc и, по идее, все заработает.

Comment: @KoVadim в комментариях к этому файлу написано, что он для libreadline, так что я подозреваю, что не то

Comment: ну, а что там должно быть написано? правда меня смущает желания автора вопроса - обычно Ctrl+r выполняет другие действия

Comment: да, мне нужно копать в сторону inputrc. спасибо

Comment: правда у меня есть сомнения по поводу правого control'а. Но это такое